# codeigniter url routing not working when doing with multiple language

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

In codeigniter I am routing my url `www.xxxxxx.com/jewels` to `www.xxxxxx.com/luxury-jewels` by using the following code in `routes.php`,

```
$route['(.*)luxury-jewels'] = "jewels";
```

the above code working well for english language when i am my other language its adding new parameter `"ru"` in the URL For Example:

`www.xxxxxx.com/ru/luxury-jewels` when doing this i am getting 404 Page Not Found error.

I tried different routing combinations its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intend of using

```
$route['(.*)luxury-jewels'] = "jewels";
```

use

```
$route['(:any)/luxury-jewels'] = "jewels";
```

Tested and works for me.

Comment: when i remove this code $route['^(en|ru)/(.+)$'] = "$2"; its working but other pages not working

Comment: instead of $route['^(en|ru)/(.+)$'] = "$2";  use  $route['^(:any)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

Comment: $route['^(:any)/(.+)$'] = "$2"; when i change this also not working.. language change controller not changing

Comment: which function you are using to change language? can you share it?

Comment: i have fixed it there is a placement issue... thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another route for it.

e.g

```
$route['ru/luxury-jewels'] = "jewels";
```

or 
for many languages

```
$route['(:any)/luxury-jewels'] = "jewels";
```